# can Xamarin.forms automatically check for login details before launching the screen?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, autologin

So in my application on launch a login screen is shown, a user enters username and password, and if they close the application without logging out when they open it again they just press login within filling in the Username and password fields and it opens, so I want to ask is there a way so my application can check for the login details (saved in php) ? and if login details are valid it skips the login screen but if login details are not valid it takes the user to the login screen. is there a way I can implement it?

Comment: Yes.  You can do it in the App's OnStartup method, or you could do it in a placeholder page that then either navigates to the login or another page, or do it in the login page itself.  There are many different ways you could implement this.

Comment: The Question is how exactly can I implement it ? Like the onLoginClicked method I have cant be implemented outside of the ViewModel so I'm Kind of Stuck on how can I check it in the first place, Im kind of new to Xamarin.

Comment: you haven't posted any code that demonstrates what you're doing so its difficult to give specific advice.  Why can't the code be executed outside of the VM?  Why couldn't it be placed in a helper or services class where both `OnStartup` and the VM can both call it?